# currency switcher Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, price, frontend, currency

I set currency switcher from admin panel.

Its show on frontend as a **dropdown**,
when I select other currency,its not working.

Comment: which issue you are facing?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya price not change i like first my price in dollar and now i want euro when i slect euro from dropdown price remain same

Comment: @DhirenVasoya how?? Can u please  tell me

Answer (score 0):

**Update a currency rate**

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to `Stores > Currency > Currency Rates`.
2. Enter the new value for each currency supported.
3. When complete, click Save Currency Rates.

After doing above things, run the upgrade, deploy and caching commands and then check.

Comment: Hii @Dhiren can i change value for custom showing prices like i want to change price only for this($_product->getSpecialPrice())

Comment: yes you can able to do that one.

Comment: How, can u please you tell me ??

Comment: For the different question, ask the question separately so other community member can also help you.